# How to connect Nucleo-32 L432KC (stm32) to Mac using DFU

Tags: arduino, stm32, nucleo, stm32cubeide

I'm doing my first steps using STM32 board, and it's pretty complicated so far...
I'm trying to use the Nucleo-32 L432KC board since I need to build a prototype device that runs on batteries and the ESP-32 on which I built my original Arduino app just drained the batteries in a couple of days at best.

So I moved to `STM32 Nucleo-32 L432KC` board so get longer battery life, but unfortunately I found that even when running this board with nothing connected to it, just the board with the LEDs that automatically turned on, just that consumes about 30mA in standby mode when installing the software using Arduino IDE.

So I tried to get some knowledge around the web, and figured out that in order to shut those LEDs down and do some more steps toward consuming less power, I need to use STM32Cube Programmer and that I can connect my board to it using USB DFU which I'm not familiar with at all.
So I got to it, and tried to connect my board to start messing around with firmware, but unfortunately STM32Cube Programmer did not recognize any DFU connected.

Everywhere I look around the web, I see many explanations about other boards, but on that specific one I can't find anything, and the official docs are not too understandable to a junior like me...

I read that I need to set the board to a DFU mode, but I have no idea how to do so. I also read about some pin called BOOT0, but I can't see any pin with that name on my board.

The only approach I have to this board is uploading my software using Arduino IDE and a USB cable.

So I need help, is there anyone that might be familiar with how to set the STM32 NUCLEO-32 L432KC board to DFU Mode and connect it to the STM32Cube Programmer app on MacOS?